# how to insert a map of lists into mongodb using mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I have the following list which is put into a map.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(301);
list.add(302);
list.add(303);

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
map.put(300, list);

map.get(300); // [301,302,303]
```

how do I store this map in mongoDB using MongoTemplate ??

Comment: You need to create a `DBObject`, and populate it as `DBObject obj = new DBObject(300,list)` and save it.